# Do we need [error-correction] of the [fault-tolerance]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-merge

I am wondering whether the tags [error-correction](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-correction) and [fault-tolerance](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fault-tolerance) can/should be merged. They seem to relate to the same topic: prevention/correction of errors.

What is your opinion towards merging these tags?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Keep them both as separate tags

While heavily related and often talked about together, they are slightly different things:

[*Quantum Error Correction* (QEC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_error_correction) is using a 'code' (e.g. [Shor code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_error_correction#The_Shor_code) or [Stabiliser code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stabilizer_code)) to mitigate errors that occur when performing operations on a processor.

However, if a system has a lot of noise, QEC may not work well enough to stop the errors from changing the final result. Similarly, as an example, if a bit flip $\left(X\right)$ code is used and $Z$ errors occur, the system is not *fault tolerant* to that noise/error.

The *fault tolerance threshold* is the point where noise is low enough for QEC to be used to make the system fault tolerant.

In this sense, while fault tolerance requires QEC, QEC alone does not make a system fault tolerant, so I believe they are sufficiently different to warrant having separate, non-synonymous tags

Comment: If they're kept separate, they probably call for strong tag wikis and excerpts.

Comment: Two separate Tags. To use conventional computer terminology as an analogy: error correction is ECC memory, fault tolerance is dual HD, Power Supplies, etc. -- please leave separate or person should justify merging. 

Comment: @EmilioPisanty The community members are working hard to complete all the tag wiki and excerpts. So, that will be done.

Comment: +1. I agree with this answer. Let's keep them separate.